# What is a suitable algorithm for solving a large mixed-integer quadratic program?

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I am interested in the solutions of a very large quadratic programming (QP) problem

\begin{align}
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} & x^T Q x\\
\mathrm{subject\ to} & A x = b\\
& x \in \{0,1\}^n
\end{align}

where $n=10^7$, $Q$ is a dense, positive-semidefinite matrix whose entries are natural numbers that can be computed rapidly, and $A \in \mathbb{N}^{n \times 20}$.

What is a suitable algorithm for such a large problem, and what is a good implementation?

Comment: Do you mean a mixed-integer quadratic program (MIQP)?

Comment: It would be useful to hear what you already tried?

Comment: Did you mean $A$ to be $20\times n$ instead of $n \times 20$?

Comment: It seems to me that the key here is that it is simply impractical to form Q or its square root. This is going to rule out most traditional MINLP solvers, frankly, including I think both of the suggestions below. Is this a fair assessment?

Answer (score 1):

This is a mixed-integer QP, not a positive semidefinite QP. (One can make any QP with binary constraints psd by adding a large multiple of $x^Tx-e^Tx$.)

Couenne ( https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne ) might be an appropriate solver for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [GloMIQO](http://helios.princeton.edu/GloMIQO/). It's available in GAMS (as of version 23.8) and designed specifically to solve mixed-integer quadratic programs with linear or quadratic constraints, and has some promising results. You could also try contacting the authors of the software directly, if purchasing a GAMS license is not a viable option.